# Multiply nested pairs of list values in Clojure

Tags: clojure

What I am ultimately trying to do is multiply two vectors together and return a vector of the same size eg:

```
[6 7 8 9 10] * [0 1 3 1 0] => [0 7 24 9 0]
```

I was attempting to do something like:

```
(partition 2 (interleave [6 7 8 9 10] [0 1 3 1 0])) => ((6 0) (7 1) (8 3) (9 1) (10 0))
```

... then multiply each nested list value and use `flatten` to get:

```
(0 7 24 9 0)
```

but I cant figure out how I could multiply nested list values?

Comment: You can get the intermediate value by “zipping” the vecs: `(map vector [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]) ; => ([1 4 7] [2 5 8] [3 6 9])`. But `map` is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map takes multiple sequences and a function to combine each member with the corresponding member of the other sequences.

```
user> (map * [6 7 8 9 10] [0 1 3 1 0])
(0 7 24 9 0)
user> (mapv * [6 7 8 9 10] [0 1 3 1 0])
[0 7 24 9 0]
```

in this case it calls `*` on the first number from each list, then on the second from each list and so on, building a seq of the output. If you would prefer the output in a vector `mapv` is convenient.